# Java NullPointerException when calling from an abstract class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, abstract

I am trying to simply extend an abstract class in Java and call a few methods stored in it. I keep getting NullPointerException when I do so. Am I missing something about abstraction here?

This is the parent class:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public Color color;
    public Point center;
    public double rotation;

    public Shape() {
        Color color = new Color();
        Point center = new Point();
        rotation = 0.0;
        System.out.println("shape created");
    }

    public void setLocation( Point p ) { center.locationX = p.locationX; center.locationY = p.locationY; }
    public void setLocation( double x, double y ) { center.locationX = x; center.locationY = y; }

    public abstract double calcArea();
    public abstract boolean draw();
}
```

And the child class:

```
public class Ellipse extends Shape {        
    public Ellipse() {
    }

    public double calcArea() {
        return 0.0;
    }

    public boolean draw() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You might want to see Point:

```
public class Point {
    public double locationX;
    public double locationY;

    public Point() {
        locationX = 0.0;
        locationY = 0.0;
    }
}
```

And finally the main function:

```
public class MakeShapes {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Ellipse myShapes = new Ellipse();
        myShapes.setLocation( 100.0, 100.0 );
    }
}
```

As soon as I use the setLocation(), I get the NPE. Any thoughts? My brain hurts from trying to figure this out. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide a stack trace of the exception, and indicate in the code where it occurs.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that your `Shape` constructor creates a local `Point` reference called `center` and initilizes that one instead of intializing the field (and you have the same problem with `color`). Try like this:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public Color color;
    public Point center;
    public double rotation;

    public Shape() {
        color = new Color(); //changed to intialize the field
        center = new Point(); //changed to intialize the field
        rotation = 0.0;
        System.out.println("shape created");
    }

    public void setLocation( Point p ) { center.locationX = p.locationX; center.locationY = p.locationY; }
    public void setLocation( double x, double y ) { center.locationX = x; center.locationY = y; }

    public abstract double calcArea();
    public abstract boolean draw();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a subtle bug.  You are creating a local `center` variable and not assigning it to `this.center`

```
    public Shape() {
        Color color = Color.BLACK;
        Point center = new Point();
        rotation = 0.0;
        System.out.println("shape created");
    }
```

change the `color` and `center` declaration to be to `this.`

`this.center = new Point()`

In the end `this.center` is never actually defined and hence the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above.

You are creating an instance of another object inside the constructor which is deleted once out of scope. 
So, you weren't actually setting the members of the object.